# Forcing external apps to use the API

Tags: rest, api

I have a website allowing authenticated users to submit and edit data. I also want to offer a REST API as part of a chargeable service. 
Now the problem is that a non-paying user could theoretically use the same calls my website uses as API for authentication and sending data from his external application since it is very easy in the browser to see the endpoint what and how exactly the data is being sent to a website.

How can I protect my website from such usage and force the user to use API for external access?

Comment: You can authenticate individual users on the API. Make them use a token/username and password to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot prevent people making requests to a public API. You can just validate the user when a request arrives. So there are more than one approach to solve this problem.

I would provide a token per session for each user and validate the rest API request at back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Use OAuth2. So you will give paid user secret id and key then they will ask for the access token to access the API's using secret id and key.

Read about public/private key encryption https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Read about oAuth 
https://oauth.net/2/

I have used passport to implement oAuth2 in laravel. passport is oAuth2 implementation and available in other languages also.